# Wolfram Language Paclet Repository minimum version

Tags: packages, paclets

I'm thinking of moving my [EcoEvo package](https://github.com/cklausme/EcoEvo) to the [Wolfram Language Paclet Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository). [This page](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/guidelines) says that Mathematica v13.0 is required for development, but I'm interested in the minimum version for users.  What is the oldest version of Mathematica that WLPR supports for users?

(cross-posted to [Wolfram Community](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2688482))

Comment: @ConnorGray any info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from Bob Sandheinrich over at [Wolfram Community](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2688482): 12.1 is the minimum version.